# Use Hyperlink in code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, hyperlink

how can i use a asp:hyperlink in my code where the user can press the number and go to another page, so this is my code,

```
if (dt != null)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        loggedin.Text = "Registered users today: " + dr["RegisteredUsersToday"];
                    }
                    if (dtParent != null)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dtParent.Rows)
                        {

                            loggedinParents.Text = "Registered Parents today: " + dr["RegisteredUsersToday"];

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        loggedinParents.Text = "Registered Parents today: 0 ";
                    }
                    if (dtTeacher != null)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dtTeacher.Rows)
                        {

                            loggedinTeachers.Text = "Registered Teachers today: " + dr["RegisteredUsersToday"];

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        loggedinTeachers.Text = "Registered Teachers today: 0 ";
                    }

                    if (dtStudents != null)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dtStudents.Rows)
                        {

                            loggedinStudents.Text = "Registered Students today: " + dr["RegisteredUsersToday"];

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        loggedinStudents.Text = "Registered Students today: 0 ";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    loggedin.Text = "No new users today";
                }
```

i want the hyperlink to be between RegisteredUsersToday, and this is my html where a have created the labels,

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                              <div class="text-center panel-heading">
                                 <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"  >
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="loggedin"></asp:Label>

                                 </a>
                              </div>
                              <br />
                              <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                 <div class="text-center">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server"   ID="loggedinParents"></asp:Label>
                                 </div>
                                 <br />
                                 <div class="text-center">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server"   ID="loggedinTeachers"></asp:Label>
                                 </div>
                                 <br />
                                 <div class="text-center">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server"   ID="loggedinStudents"></asp:Label>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
```

Comment: You mean "Press" as in press a key on the keyboard?

Comment: No no, with the mouse, i need like like in html is <a href ="link">some</a>, but this time in the code not in the html, @Icemanind

Comment: Then you just do this: `<asp:HyperLink id="link1" NavigateUrl="mypage.html" Text="Click me!" runat="server" />`. Optionally, you can add `Target="_new"` to open it in a new window. The documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink(v=vs.110).aspx)